# How to create a enumerated data type in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I want to create a enumerated data type. in the following format.

```
set module {
    0 { type { XXX}
        type_name { yyy}
        inst_name {ppp}
        lib {jjjj } 
        is_cw {0/1}
        pll_to_top { merged/propogated}
    }

    1 { type {....}
        type_name {......}
        inst_name {........}
        lib {......}
    }

    2  ......

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a dictionary (introduced in Tcl 8.5). You create them in pretty much the form you've written out there, and then you can look them up with:

```
set zero_lib [dict get $module 0 lib]
```

---

Alternatively, if you're stuck back in 8.4 then you do:

```
array set ary $module
array set subary $ary(0)
set zero_lib $subary(lib)
```

This isn't very efficient!